# Screen shots shortcuts disabling themselves (Yosemite)

Tags: keyboard, macos, screen-capture, shortcut

I use screen shots all the time (Cmd+Shift+4 ftw). But suddenly, I'll go to take a screen shot and the shortcut doesn't work. I go into System Preferences > Keyboard and see that ALL the screen shot shortcuts are unchecked. I check the shortcuts on, but then a few seconds later, they will be unchecked. I click Restore Defaults to turn them on, but they still disable a few seconds later.

Has anyone else had this? What could be causing it?

Even if I want to take a screen shot during this, I don't have enough time after checking the box to press the shortcut before it turns back off.

Thank you in advance to anyone who offers assistance.

Comment: I'd run a prefs & disk check from Disk Utility as a first step

Answer (score 1):

If the user preferences are not sticking or been changed there are 2 possibility.

1- You have a app that does that.

2-You Permissions need repair, using the Disk Utility.- usualy Start with this step first.